# Converting a Swift Completion Closure to C#

Tags: c#, swift, delegates, closures, completionhandler

I'm porting a library from Swift to C# and I'm having trouble converting a completion handler to C#.

**In Swift I have:**

```
public typealias myChangeHandler = (progress: Double, myView: MyCustomView)

private var myChangeClosure: myChangeHandler?

public func myChangeClosure(_ completion: myChangeHandler) {
    myChangeClosure = completion
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
myChangeClosure?(progress: myProgress, view: self)
```

or like this:

```
localInstance.myChangeClosure() {
    (progress: Double, myView: MyCustomView) in 
    textLabel.text = "\(Int(progress * 100.0))%"
}
```

**In C#, I've attempted the same like this:**

```
Func<double, MyCustomView> MyChangeType;

public void MyChangeClosure(Func<double, MyCustomView> completion) 
{
    MyChangeType = completion;
}
```

Which I am unable to call using similar syntax to Swift:

```
MyChangeType(myProgress, (MyCustomView)this); // bad job :'(
```

### My Question

How can I convert the Swift completion functionality above to C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Func first generic is the return type, which is the double in your case.  What you want is to use an Action :

```
Action<double, MyCustomView> MyChangeType;
```

Then you can use it just like you want to :

```
MyChangeType(myProgress, (MyCustomView)this); // good job :)
```

You can take a look at this webpage for further explanation :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/delegate-vs-action-vs-func1

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly, I'll take a minute to read the article you provided